# trigger form filling by onClick or onChange on checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox, triggers

I have forms (input text) that I want to be filled by checkbox click or change trigger. So if user click the checkbox, it will fire the javascript function to fill the form with values from php queries.

The problem is, I have many forms. So here I make many javascript functions to handle each form filling. Here is the javascript code:

```js
<script language="javascript">
function copyProfile1(){
 document.getElementById("author1fname").value  = <?php echo json_encode($query_user['firstName']); ?>;
 document.getElementById("author1lname").value  = <?php echo json_encode($query_user['lastName']); ?>;
 document.getElementById("author1inst").value  = <?php echo json_encode($query_user['institution']); ?>;
}
function copyProfile2(){
 document.getElementById("author2fname").value  = <?php echo json_encode($query_user['firstName']); ?>;
 document.getElementById("author2lname").value  = <?php echo json_encode($query_user['lastName']); ?>;
 document.getElementById("author2inst").value  = <?php echo json_encode($query_user['institution']); ?>;
}
</script>
```

And here is the HTML:

```html
<div class="form-group">
   <h3><strong>Author(s)</strong> <small>limited to 4 authors</small></h3>
   <div class="row">
   <!-- 1st author -->
   <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="box box-success">
     <div class="box-header with-border">
       <h3 class="box-title">1st Author</h3>
     </div>
     <div class="box-body">
     <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="auth1check" onClick="copyProfile1()">
        Check here if this is you
      </label>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input type="text" name="author1fname" id="author1fname" class="form-control" placeholder="Firstname">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input type="text" name="author1lname" id="author1lname" class="form-control" placeholder="Lastname">
      </div>
       </div><br />
       <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
      <input type="text" name="author1inst" id="author1inst" class="form-control" placeholder="Institution">
      </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <!-- /.box-body -->
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- end of 1st author -->
</div>
<div class="row">
   <!-- 2nd author -->
   <div class="col-sm-3" id="author2"style="display:none;">
    <div class="box box-success">
     <div class="box-header with-border">
       <h3 class="box-title">2nd Author</h3>
     </div>
     <div class="box-body">
       <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="auth2check" onClick="copyProfile2()">
        Check here if this is you
      </label>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input type="text" name="author2fname" id="author2fname" class="form-control" placeholder="Firstname">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input type="text" name="author2lname" id="author2lname" class="form-control" placeholder="Lastname">
      </div>
       </div><br />
       <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
      <input type="text" name="author2inst" id="author2inst" class="form-control" placeholder="Institution">
      </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <!-- /.box-body -->
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- end of 2nd author -->
</div>
</div>
```

Actually I have 7 forms, but here I just copy 2 of them in snippet. This code is working well. But I think there must be more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just add a parameter on the function

```
function copyProfile(fName, lName, institution){
    //change the hardcoded id's to your parameter name
    document.getElementById(fName).value    = <?php echo json_encode($query_user['firstName']); ?>;
    document.getElementById(lName).value    = <?php echo json_encode($query_user['lastName']); ?>;
    document.getElementById(institution).value  = <?php echo json_encode($query_user['institution']); ?>;
}
```

then you can just invoke that `copyProfile()` anytime you wanted to use it.

```
copyProfile(<enter fname here>, <enter lname here>, <enter institution here>);
```

that way you don't need to create lots of copyProfile function.

if you want to copy profile 1

> copyProfile("author1fname", "author1lname", "author1institution");

if you want to copy profile 2

> copyProfile("author2fname", "author12name", "author2institution");

and so on and so forth.

**EDIT:** Updated my answer on how you should invoke the **copyProfile** function

Comment: Wow. How cant I realize that solution. Thank you @JF-Mechs

I tried to modify my code as this:
'<input type="checkbox" id="auth1check" onClick="copyProfile(author1fname, author1lname, author1inst)">'

But it still doesnt work

Comment: you are doing it wrong . you should invoke `copyProfile()` like this

`copyProfile("author1fname", "author1lname", "author1inst")` .. you wrote them as object and those 3 params are not defined in your page so basically they return undefined

Comment: If my answer really helps you, please click the check icon on the left side to accept my answer.. have a nice coding day! :)